# ComponentDidUpdate() keeps getting called slows the process down (Axios)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I receive some data using Axios and show them in a drop down menu:

```
  refreshList() {
    axios.get('/api/jobs/list-locations/',{headers:headers}).then(res=>{
      this.setState({
        locations:res.data.map(Locations=>({label:[Locations.country,' ', Locations.region,' ',Locations.zipcode],value:Locations.id}))
      })
    })
    axios.get('/api/jobs/list-departments',{headers:headers}).then(resp=>{
      this.setState({
        departments:resp.data.map(departments=>({label:[departments.name,' ',departments.company_name],value:departments.id}))
      })
    })
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.refreshList()
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.refreshList()
  }
```

Next to each of those drop down menus there is an option for adding a new object (new location or new department) and when you create a new object in these forms it gets posted to the API using axios. Since I wanted the options to get loaded in real time without refreshing, I used a `componentDidUpdate()`.
this worked well when only the locations had an "add new location" feature, but as soon as I added this option for departments ComponentDidUpdate fills the browser console with errors and the processes and showing new items in the list get very slow. Here's the rest of my code continuing from the previous part:

```
render() {

    let addModalLocClose = () => this.setState({addModalLocShow:false})
    let addModalDepClose = () => this.setState({addModalDepShow:false})
    return (
           <Row>
          <Col xs={10}>
            <Select placeholder='Select from pre-created Locations'onChange={handleDropDown('Location')} defaultValue={values.Location} required options={this.state.locations}/> 
          </Col>
          <Col>
          <Button style={{position:'relative',left:'150px' }} onClick={()=>this.setState({addModalLocShow: true})} color='success'>
            New Locations
         </Button>
         <AddLocModal show={this.state.addModalLocShow} onHide={addModalLocClose} /> 
          </Col>
        </Row>  

        <br />
        <Row>
         <Col xs={10}>
          <Select placeholder='Select from pre-created Departments'onChange={handleDropDown('Department')} defaultValue={values.Department} required options={this.state.departments}/>
         </Col>
        <Col>
          <Button style={{position:'relative',left:'150px', width:'130px'}} onClick={()=>this.setState({addModalDepShow: true})} color='success'>
            New Department
          </Button>
          <AddDepModal show={this.state.addModalDepShow} onHide={addModalDepClose} />
        </Col>
```

and in my pop up form component where the data gets posted for example **(AddLocModal.js)**

```
export class AddLocModal extends Component {

  handleSubmit (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log('handlesubmitshot')

    const headers = {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: 'Token 3a4efb52af35873353a27491ffe54e6551c61391'
    }

    const location = {
      country: event.target.LocationCountry.value,
      region: event.target.LocationRegion.value,
      zip_code: event.target.LocationZipCode.value
    }
    axios(
      {
        method: 'post',
        url: '/api/jobs/set-location/',
        headers: headers,
        data: location
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        this.props.onLocationAdded()
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.response)
      })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Modal
        {...this.props}
        size='lg'
        aria-labelledby='contained-modal-title-vcenter'
        centered
      >
 <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <Row>
......
```

how can I fix this issue?
Edit: browser error :net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `refreshList` every single time the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method gets triggered because you will end up with an infinite re-rendering of your component. I suggest you use the parameters that `componentDidUpdate` provides - `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot)` and only call `refreshList` if some condition evaluates to `true`, instead of every single time a component gets updated. Exactly the way they have it in the docs - https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Comment: @goto1 but how can I use them? refreshList() receives some items and I want to re-receive them when a new Item gets posted. I dont know how to make this match a special condition

Comment: if you could create a minimal reproducible example in something like `CodeSandbox` that' be easier for me to debug and look at.

Answer (score 1):

As Reactjs offical docs:
[componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
  if (this.props.userID !== prevProps.userID) {
    this.fetchData(this.props.userID);
  }
}
```

> You may call setState() immediately in componentDidUpdate() but note that it must be wrapped in a condition like in the example above, or you’ll cause an infinite loop...

So you should have a check before refresh list to avoid infinite loop.